# Postgresql doesn't use partial index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Postgresql 9.3

I have a table with date_field:

```
date_field timestamp without time zone

CREATE INDEX ix__table__date_field ON table USING btree (date_field)
    WHERE date_field IS NOT NULL;
```

Then I've tried to use my partial index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) from table where date_field is not null;

Aggregate  (cost=29048.22..29048.23 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=41.714..41.714 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on table  (cost=0.00..28138.83 rows=363755 width=0) (actual time=41.711..41.711 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (date_field IS NOT NULL)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 365583
Total runtime: 41.744 ms
```

But it uses partial index with comparing dates:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) from table where date_field > '2015-1-1';

Aggregate  (cost=26345.51..26345.52 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table  (cost=34.60..26040.86 rows=121861 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (date_field > '2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix__table__date_field  (cost=0.00..4.13 rows=121861 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (date_field > '2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Total runtime: 0.037 ms
```

So, why it doesn't use index on `date_field is not null`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems your statistics are not up to date. Run `analyze the_table_name` and then try again.

Comment: Are null values very few compared to rows of the table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's true! I will accept your answer when you make it an official one. Thanks!